# how to force recent calls activity to show contact's name on insert

Tags: java, android, smartphone

I am trying to insert a new call on my HTC programmatically.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, someNumber);
values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, someName);
values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE, 0);
values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, "");
values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE, someTime);
values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION, someDuration);
values.put(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NEW, 1);
contentResolver.insert(uri, values);
```

Well, the call shows up in the list but I always see (unknown) rather than the CACHED_NAME. The same code works well on Samsung but sucks on HTC for some reason. Is it a bug like behaviour on HTC or am I missing some things here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrighty. After a deep investigation I found out the reason. HTC devices for some reason are retrieving caller names from another field called "cname" rather than

```
android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME="name"
```

Using the following will do the trick:

```
String static final HTC_CACHED_NAME="cname"
if (isHTCDevice) 
    values.put(HTC_CACHED_NAME, someName);
...
```

Let me know!

Comment: I tried that workaround but I get an exception on my HTC Desire HD running 2.3.3.  Did you manage to find another workaround?

Comment: Your HTC has a different field name I believe. Try dumping out the column names and find out what name your device uses.

Comment: mine uses "name" and still not doing it the right way, HTC sucks X-(